# Как сделать кликабельный список QListWidget?

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qlistwidget

Задача: в окошке виджета *PyQt* вывести имеющийся список так, чтобы элементы списка были кликабельными и можно было привязать к каждому обработчик события клика.

Везде нахожу примеры обработчика для нажатия кнопки, а мне для элементов списка нужно. 
Подскажите, можно ли такое сделать и куда смотреть?

Comment: Копайте в сторону QListWidget, или QListView

Comment: Можно и QTableWidget посмотреть, потому как имеет метод setCellWidget, что даёт возможность сунуть любой виджет в ячейку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам достаточно сигнала `itemClicked`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication)

LISTS = ("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5",)

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.l = QListWidget()
        self.l.addItems(LISTS)

        self.l.itemClicked.connect(self.selectionChanged)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.l)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def selectionChanged(self, item):
        print("Вы кликнули: {}".format(item.text()))
        if item.text()=="item2": print("Делайте что-нибудь.")
        # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]